# How to adjust the width of the rectangle of a pgfplots figure?

Tags: pgfplots

I know I can use `\pgfplotsset{widht=8cm}` to adjust the width of whole figure, but I care more about the width of rectangle.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}


\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=newest}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {
(0,0)
(1,1)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: So you mean the height of the figure? Otherwise, can you clearify your need ...

Comment: The option `scale only axis=true`, which you can paste in your `axis` environment sets the width for your axis, not the whole picture, if this is your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, `scale only axis=true` only sets the length of the axis, not the whole picture.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[
                name=a,
                width=8cm,
                height=8cm,
                scale=1,
            ]
            \addplot[
                blue,
                mark=*,
                fill=blue,
            ] coordinates {
                (0,0)
                (1,1)
            };
        \end{axis}
    
    \draw[orange, densely dashed] (0,-0.25) -- (8,-0.25);
    
        \begin{axis}[
                at={($(a.south west) - (0,0.5cm)$)},
                anchor=north west,
                scale only axis=true,
                width=8cm,
                height=8cm,
            ]
            \addplot[
                blue,
                mark=*,
                fill=blue,
            ] coordinates {
                (0,0)
                (1,1)
            };
        \end{axis}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

The orange line indicates a width of 8 cm.